# Associations challenge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm new to rails and I'm stucked in an association problem. I made a many-to-many association between meals and ingredients. I used cocoon to make the meals form but the problem is: I must set the quantity of each ingredient in my meal but I can't store it in the ingredients database, therefore I set this column in the meals database. What can I do? Should I make another model for quantities? Is there any other association I can use?

This is my git repo:
https://github.com/betinhosaad/inutree

[To illustrate my question and making another one about totals =P](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhd61.png)

> EDITED
>  Well I changed my database and put a `:quantity` in the
>   connector. After that I used the binding.pry and checked the params
>   I'm receiving in the create action:
>
> ```
>  "meal"=>{"name"=>"quatro",
>  "ingredients_attributes"=>{"1449271563126"=>{"name"=>"quatro",
>  "unit"=>"und",
>  "carb"=>"4",
>  "prot"=>"4",
>  "fat"=>"4",
>  "ing_quantity"=>"4",
>  "_destroy"=>"false"}}},
>  "commit"=>"Create Meal"
> ```
>
> this `ing_quantity` is an action I have defined in the Ingredient
>   model and called in the `_ingredient_fields.html.erb` as `<%=
>   f.text_field :ing_quantity, required: true, class: "form-control" %>`
>   and:
>
> ```
> class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
>  has_many :meal_ingredients
>  has_many :meals, through: :meal_ingredients 
>
> def ing_quantity
>     meal_ingredients(:quantity)
>   end
>
>   def ing_quantity=(quantity)
>     self.meal_ingredients = MealIngredient.find_or_create_by(quantity: quantity)
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> Now I'm getting this error: `undefined method 'each' for <MealIngredient:0x007f9c7ecc5b10>`
>
> I don't know if this is a silly question and I already spent too much
>   time on this and can't think properly but can't figure it out how can
>   I send the quantity directly to the meal_ingredients table and then get these values associated

Answer (score 1):

I would create a join model that `belongs_to` each of the items. You can use a generator like so: `bundle exec rails g model meal_ingredient meal:references ingredient:references quantity:integer` which will generate the following model.

class MealIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meal
  belongs_to :ingredient
end

You will then want to update `Meal` to have:

`has_many :meal_ingredients
has_many :ingredients, through: :meal_ingredient`

and update `Ingredient` to:

`has_many :meal_ingredients
mas_many :meals, through: :meal_ingredients`

You only need to add the `has_many` on the ingredients if you wish to access the associated models from an ingredient instance.

You can then create the `MealIngredient` instances and set a quantity on the instance.

Comment: I already have this model, I just didn't realize I could put the quantitiy in this connector. And how can I call this param in the cocoon _ingredient_fields.html.erb file?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with that gem but you should be able to just add quality as a field on the instance.

Comment: Looking at [this view](https://github.com/betinhosaad/inutree/blob/master/app/views/meals/_ingredient_fields.html.erb) it seems like you need to iterate over the ingredients to access the quantities required